# JavaScript: Detecting duplicate elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a small script that should detect duplicate elements in an array of fields on a form.

```
function dupes() {
    var unique = [];
    //Loop through array of fields to get entered values
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        unique[i] = Number(document.getElementById('proj' + i).value);
    }
    unique.sort();
    //Now compare the array values. If there are any duplicates, throw an error
    for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        if (unique[i] == unique[i - 1]) {
            document.getElementById('errormsg').innerHTML = 'duplicated values!';
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

There are ten of these "proj" fields (proj0 - proj9), and I have an onClick event assigned to call this function. If there are any duplicate values, the span 'errormsg' is supposed to display an error, but it's not working. What might I be missing?

Comment: Any errors on the console? Could you provide a simple fiddle?

Comment: @epascarello: you noticed the array is sorted?

Comment: Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W9YgF/1/

Comment: See my answer, with working fiddle demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Check for duplicate project numbers
function errorCheck() {
    var unique = [];
    //Loop through array of fields to get entered values
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        var currentValue = Number(document.getElementById('projNo' + i).value);
        if(unique.indexOf(currentValue)!=-1)
        {
            document.getElementById('projError').innerHTML = 'duplicated values!';
            return false;
        }
        unique[i]=currentValue;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[**FiddleDEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/W9YgF/2/)

It first checks whether a value is already in the array by using `unique.indexOf(currentValue)`. This function returns the index of the searched element and returns -1 if it is not found.
If it was not found, it adds it to the array and goes to the next one.

**Edit:**

If you want to reset the error message when you submit again and there are no more duplicates, don't forget to reset it before `return true;` like so:

```
document.getElementById('projError').innerHTML = 'no duplicates ;)';
```

Comment: Can you explain why the original (more efficient) script did not work?

Comment: @Bergi After actually looking at the OP's JS Fiddle, it does seem to work, he just forgot to set the `No wrap - in <body>` option in jsFiddle :/ Did not see that. In terms of efficiency, you might be right, I just thought the difference was minimal when applying it to 10 values.

Answer (score 0):

This will detect the duplicate values :

```
  var arr= [];
    //Loop through array of fields to get entered values
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        arr.push(Number(document.getElementById('proj' + i).value));
    }

function dupes(arr) { // pass the array to find dupes
  var i, len=arr.length,  unique= [], obj={};

  for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
    obj[arr[i]]=0;
  }
  for (i in obj) {
    unique.push(i);
  }
  if(unique.length != arr.length) {
      document.getElementById('errormsg').innerHTML = 'duplicated values!';
  }
}

dupes(arr);
```